# JToken NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, json.net

I'm getting a null reference exception when I run this code.

```
        string[] champsArray = File.ReadAllLines(@"ListOfChamps.txt");
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionnaryChamps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var jsonFile = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Fayss\Desktop\data.json"));
        foreach (var x in champsArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(jsonFile["data"][x]["key"]);
        }
```

I'm trying to print every key of every name of the file ListOfChamps.txt

Here is the content of the text file ListOfChamps:

```
Aatrox
Ahri
Akali 
Alistar 
Amumu 
Anivia 
Annie 
Aphelios 
Ashe 
AurelionSol 
Azir 
Bard 
Blitzcrank 
Brand 
Braum 
Caitlyn 
Camille 
Cassiopeia 
Chogath 
Corki 
Darius 
Diana 
Draven 
DrMundo 
Ekko 
Elise 
Evelynn 
Ezreal 
Fiddlesticks 
Fiora 
Fizz 
Galio 
Gangplank 
Garen 
Gnar 
Gragas 
Graves 
Hecarim 
Heimerdinger Illaoi 
Irelia 
Ivern 
Janna 
JarvanIV 
Jax 
Jayce Jhin 
Jinx 
Kaisa 
Kalista 
Karma 
Karthus 
Kassadin 
Katarina 
Kayle 
Kayn 
Kennen 
Khazix 
Kindred 
Kled 
KogMaw 
Leblanc 
LeeSin 
Leona 
Lillia 
Lissandra 
Lucian 
Lulu 
Lux 
Malphite 
Malzahar 
Maokai 
MasterYi 
MissFortune 
MonkeyKing 
Mordekaiser 
Morgana 
Nami 
Nasus 
Nautilus 
Neeko 
Nidalee 
Nocturne 
Nunu 
Olaf 
Orianna 
Ornn 
Pantheon 
Poppy 
Pyke 
Qiyana 
Quinn 
Rakan 
Rammus 
RekSai 
Rell 
Renekton 
Rengar 
Riven 
Rumble 
Ryze 
Samira 
Sejuani 
Senna 
Seraphine 
Sett 
Shaco 
Shen 
Shyvana 
Singed 
Sion 
Sivir 
Skarner 
Sona 
Soraka 
Swain 
Sylas 
Syndra 
TahmKench 
Taliyah 
Talon 
Taric 
Teemo 
Thresh 
Tristana 
Trundle 
Tryndamere 
TwistedFate 
Twitch 
Udyr 
Urgot 
Varus 
Vayne 
Veigar 
Velkoz 
Vi 
Viego 
Viktor 
Vladimir 
Volibear 
Warwick 
Xayah 
Xerath 
XinZhao 
Yasuo 
Yone 
Yorick 
Yuumi 
Zac 
Zed 
Ziggs 
Zilean 
Zoe 
Zyra
```

And here is the content of the Jsonfile data.json: [Link of data.json](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.4.1/data/en_US/champion.json)
I don't understand why I'm getting this error because it prints the first 2 keys. After that my program crashes immediately.

Comment: It's hard to tell due to the way things have come across in the question etc, but in the raw markdown `Aatrox` and `Ahri` don't have spaces after them before the newline, but `Akali` (and subsequent ones) do - if that's also the case in your actual input file, that will be enough to throw the code to not match the json data.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I't works!!! I removed the spaces with !Char.IsWhiteSpace. Thank you for your help